# React JS : All option in Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

**I have below state -**

```
const[values,setValues]=useState<IValue[]>([]);

const[value,setValue]=useState<IValue|null>();

<Autocomplete
 options={values}
 value={value}
 id="value_id"
 getOptionLabel={(option:IValue)=>`(${option.Id}) ${option.Name}`}
 renderInput={(param)=> <TextField {...param}/>}
/>

export interface IValue
{
 Id:string;
 Name : string;
}

useEffect(()=>{
//api call

setValues([...res.data]);
},[])
```

Autocomplete takes the value from Api call and sets the list.
I want to add "All" before the autocomplete list , default selected.

I tried with -

```
const[value,setValue]=useState<IValue|null>({Id="",Name="All"});
```

By this way , All appears in the list , but after making any other selection from list , it disappears.

Comment: Did you try manipulating and adding all array at the beginning  of the object of arrays coz it will than auto-populate All option as you need.

Comment: @prograk api cant send all option. I have to manage it via UI side.

Comment: Yes at UI side you can manipulate the data sent via api and add ALL option at the beginning of the object of arrays. This is one way and I'll check if AutoComplete Component of Material UI provides option to add Default and retain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried:

```
setValues([{Id:"", Name:"All"},...res.data]);
```